# Unitary operator as an exponent of self-adjoint

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, self-adjoint-operators

I'm trying to proof that set of unitary operators on infinite Hilbert space is path-connected. That's why i need to show that for each unitary $U$ there is a self-adjoint $B$ such that $U=e^{iB}$. Any ideas on how to show that? Maybe by using the fact that every unitary operator is unitary equivalent to operator of multiplication by $f$ in some $L_{2}(\mu)$ ?

Answer (score 6):

Fix a Borel function $\varphi:\mathbb T=\{z\in\mathbb C:|z|=1\}\to [0,2\pi)$ such that $e^{i\varphi(z)}=z$.  Put $B=\varphi(U)$ (here we're using Borel functional calculus).  Then $B$ is self-adjoint, and $U=\exp(iB)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! i have 2 questions - 1) are we able to take function of unitary operators? is there any way to avoid it? 2) why it turns out that $В$ is self-adjoint?

Comment: 1) Yes, the Borel functional calculus works for normal elements, and unitaries are certainly normal.  2) Because the range of $\varphi$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thank you! Can you recommend any book where i can find these facts?

Comment: I think chapter 12 of Conway's "A Course in Functional Analysis" is a great reference.  Other than that, chapter 1 or 2 of Murphy's "Operator Theory and $C^*$-algebras" should contain the information needed.

Comment: @Aweygan Sir, is there any Borel function $\varphi$ exists satisfying aforementioned condition? I mean, can you please help me to find an example of such function $\varphi$?

Comment: @abcdmath If we let $\varphi(z)=\operatorname{arg}(z)$ for $z\in\mathbb T\setminus\{1\}$ then $\varphi$ is well-defined, and continuous.  Setting $\varphi(1)=0$, we lose continuity, but $\varphi$ is still Borel, and and satisfies $e^{i\varphi(z)}=z for all $z\in\mathbb T}$.